# How to add numbers from files to computation?

Tags: awk

I need to get results of this formula - a column of numbers

```
{x = ($1-T1)/Fi; print (x-int(x))}
```

from inputs file1

```
4  4
8  4
7  78
45 2
```

file2

```
0.2
3
2
1
```

From this files should be 4 outputs.
$1 is the first column from file1, T1 is the first line in first column of the file1 (number 4) - it is alway this number, Fi, where i = 1, 2, 3, 4 are numbers from the second file. So I need a cycle for i from 1 to 4 and compute the term one times with F1=0.2, the second output with F2=3, then third output with F3=2 and the last output will be for F4=1. How to express T1 and Fi in this way and how to do a cycle?

```
awk 'FNR == NR { F[++n] = $1; next } FNR == 1 { T1 = $1 } { for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { x = ($1 - T1)/F[i]; print x - int(x) >"output" FNR} }' file2 file1
```

This gives more than 4 outputs. What is wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `FNR == 1 { T1 = $1 }` is being run twice, when `file2` is started being read `T1` is set to `0.2`,
2. `>"output" FNR` is problematic, you should enclose the output name expression in parentheses.

---

Here's how I'd do it:

```
awk '
  NR==1 {t1=$1}
  NR==FNR {f[NR]=$1; next}
  {
    fn="output"FNR
    for(i in f) {
      x=(f[i]-t1)/$1
      print x-int(x) >fn
    }
    close(fn)
  }
' file1 file2
```

Comment: This post would be dramatically improved by structured, multi-line code.

Comment: @vintnes edit it to add *structured, multi-line code* and I'll accept it. Just don't change what I already wrote

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it for not MC and I get an error about division of zero. I have 10 rows in original file2 and no empty line. Where is a problem please? Cycle work from 1 to f and f is a number of rows in file2, isn't it?

Comment: @Lukas yes, does file1 have 0 in it?

Comment: I'm sorry I had commentar in the data file. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I have five couple of file1 and file2 and I use `awk -f script.awk file1 file2` How to write a command for instance to #!/bin/sh to apply this script for all couple and keep the outputs in some "groups". I ment to add to name output some letter before for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192509/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-oguz-ismail).